# How to check if an AT command executed successfully or failed

Tags: gsm, at-command

How do I place a check programmatically if the AT command executed successfully or failed.

I have placed following check:

```
boolean success = response.endsWith("OK");
boolean failed = response.endsWith("ERROR");
```

I just want to be sure if this check can be placed universally, or atleast on AT+CUSD command. I cannot place contains check since the ussd response can itself contain 'ok' or 'error' strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent step on your behalf to investigate how to do things properly instead of just stopping on "well, this seems to work by trial and error".

Yes, `OK` and `ERROR` are universal but `ERROR` might be substituted with something else and there exists other responses as well. The [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) specification defines most of the *Final Result Codes* but additionally [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) defines `+CME ERROR:` and [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) defines `+CMS ERROR:`.

You can look at the code for [atinout](https://sourceforge.net/p/atinout/code/ci/master/tree/atinout.c) for an example for a combined `is_final_result` function, although the two split `isFinalResponseError` and `isFinalResponseSuccess` functions in ST-Ericsson's [U300 RIL](https://github.com/aferre/u300-ril/blob/master/atchannel.c) seems closer to your usage. Note however that `CONNECT` is not a final result code, it is an intermediate result code, so the name isFinalResponseSuccess is not 100% correct and you most likely do not want to include that.

Regarding contains versus endsWith it does not matter; the final result codes always comes on a line all by itself<sup>1</sup>, so you should always check that. In other words you should always only read and buffer response data from the modem until you have received a terminating `\r\n` pair of bytes and first then start parsing that received line (the absolutely only exception is when waiting for the 4 byte response from `AT+CMGS` before sending the payload).

So your structure should look something like

```
Write(port, "AT+SOMECMD\r");
do {
         input = ReadLine(port, responseTimeout);
} while (!isFinalResultCode(input));
```

If you want to consume any intermediate information text responses before the final result code comes you need to change the loop a little (e.g. check for final result code first before continuing processing the intermediate response).

---

<sup>1</sup> Provided that the end of line configuration has not been messed up, e.g. you should always let `S3` and `S4` be `\r` and `\n` as well as using `ATV1`.

Comment: I found a new modem which does the following in response to AT+CUSD command:
Returns an intermediate OK response. After 2 or 3 seconds(the normal network delay in ussd commands) it gives the actual response. Is this standard behaviour?

Comment: @djaqeel Ask that as a separate question (and tag it with [tag:at-command]), the answer is too long for a comment.

Comment: Yes sure, Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387324/atcusd-command-standard-response